# How to pass latitude-longitude to Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Directions service?

Tags: java, request

I want to use **Google Maps JavaScript API v3** in my Java Application.
For this I create **HttpGet** object with **http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false**  url.

I get the proper response, but instead of passing **Station name** I want to pass the **latitude-longitude** of the stations.

A documentation can be found at **[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)**

How can I pass latitude-longitude to this service?

**EDIT :**

When I give the URL as - **http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Jackson+Av&destination=Prospect+Av&sensor=false**    I get the proper response, but when I give URL as -

**http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.81649,73.907807&destination=40.819585,-73.90177&sensor=false**  I get the response as - ***ZERO RESULT***

Comment: I don't think you can drive from Uzgen District, Kyrgyzstan (40.7799603, 73.6065223) to Prospect Av, Bronx, NY 10455, USA (40.819585, -73.90177); you sure you don't have the sign wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create url to get as follow,

```
double lat1 = 40.74560;
   double lon1 = -73.94622000000001;
   double lat2 = 46.59122000000001;
   double lon2 = -112.004230;

   String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";

   List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("origin", lat1 + "," + lon1));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("destination", lat2 + "," + lon2));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sensor", "false"));

   String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
   url += paramString;
   HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
```

**Please check you are providing correct geoco-ordinates**

Comment: Thanks Baba for ur reply, you pointed right geocodes were wrong, this code works gr8.

Comment: what is NameValuePair and BasicNameValuePair ?

Comment: Those are part of apache lib, see docs: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/NameValuePair.html?is-external=true

Answer (score 8):

[Link to web service documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters)

Just use figures for ***latitude,longitude*** separated with a comma: for example `51,0`. Make sure there are no spaces.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51,0&destination=51.5,-0.1&sensor=false

Comment: thanks for ur reply, I tried with this but I get ZERO RESULT, plz see my Edited questions.

Comment: The lat, long that you have provided : 40.81649,73.907807 seems to be of a wrong place. Please check google maps for the location.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.81649,-73.907807&destination=40.819585,-73.90177&sensor=false is working fine

Comment: ya @rahulroc those were wrong in format, aftr giving correct geocodes I got the response

Answer (score 3):

```
var request = { 
            origin: "33.661565,73.041330",
            destination: "33.662502,73.044061",
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

This works fine

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for the v3 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests) says a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) or a string.  For geographic locations, create and pass in a google.maps.LatLng; for addresses, pass in a string.

```
origin:      LatLng | String,
destination: LatLng | String,
```

And in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest)

```
destination LatLng|string   Location of destination. This can be specified as either a string to be geocoded or a LatLng. Required.
origin      LatLng|string   Location of origin. This can be specified as either a string to be geocoded or a LatLng. Required.
```

and for a [waypoint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint):

```
location    LatLng|string   Waypoint location. Can be an address string or LatLng. Optional.
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, I have read this document also in my question I hv provided the Link. can please give me an example of passing LatLng in URL